# How to send POST request body with WebClient

Tags: java, json, post, webclient

I have method with String. I want send this String in body, using WebClient.

Below piece of clode.

```
public String JsonMethod(User user) {
        String jsonUserRegister = "{\n" +
                "    \"variables\":\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "           \"user\": \n" +
                "           {\n" +
                "               \"value\":\n" +
                "                   {\n" +
                "                \"username\": \"" + user.getUsername() + "\",\n" +
                "                \"email\": \"" + user.getEmail() + "\",\n" +
                "                \"address\": \"" + user.getAddress() + "\",\n" +
                "                \"number\": \"" + user.getNumber() + "\"\n" +
                "               } }\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "}";

        return jsonUserRegister;
    }
```

```
WebClient webClient;

public Mono<Boolean> registerUser(User user) {
    return webClient
            .post()
            .uri(URL + ":" + PORT + REST_API_REGISTER_PROCESS)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(WHAT SHOULD BE THERE?)
```

I don't know how should I call this String from method to .body

Comment: try `.body(BodyInserters.fromObject(JsonMethod(user)))`

Comment: Note that `fromObject(T)` is now deprecated as of Spring Framework 5.2, in favor of `fromValue(Object)`.